# Pyspark Streaming with Kafka in PyCharm

Tags: apache-spark, pycharm, apache-kafka, pyspark, spark-streaming

I have been recently trying to debug the pyspark.streaming.kafka class in Pycharm so that it is easier to troubleshoot compared to working on that on the linux box.

Here is my sample code:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext
from pyspark.streaming.kafka import KafkaUtils, TopicAndPartition

sc = SparkContext(appName="sample app")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
kafkaParams = {"metadata.broker.list": "{broker list}",
               "auto.offset.reset": "smallest"}
kafka_stream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, {topic list}, kafkaParams)
```

However, i got the error below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm   5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm    5.0.3\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "{script path}", line 30, in <module> {topic}], kafkaParams)
  File "C:\spark-1.6.0-bin-  hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\streaming\kafka.py", line 152, in  createDirectStream
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o20.loadClass.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:   org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka.KafkaUtilsPythonHelper
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:231)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:381)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:259)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:133)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:209)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

16/02/22 11:45:49 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
```

I would appreciate if someone can provide some guidance on how to debug the PySpark Kafka streaming module in PyCharm

Comment: How do you submit your app?

Comment: I am just using the Pycharm debug functionality.

Comment: And does it work with other configuration?

Comment: It works if i use some simple spark rdd functionality. The kafka streaming class in the pyspark library is throwing it off

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Kafka support depends on external `spark-streaming-kafka` JAR which is not shipped with Spark binaries. Typically this can be specified on submit with `--packages` argument.

For local development using PyCharm the simplest solution I can think off is to add it to `$SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-defaults.conf`. Assuming you use Spark 1.6.0 built with Scala 2.10:

```
spark.jars.packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.0
```

Keep in mind that you won't be able to use PyCharm debugger with Python worker process. See [How can pyspark be called in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31245083/1560062)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using version: spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6. I added the following files to my Pycharm intepreter: C:\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\py4j-0.9-src.zip and C:\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6\python\lib\pyspark.zip and am using pySpark instead of scala. Is there still a way to debug in Pycharm?

Comment: Pre-built binaries use Scala 2.10 so it should be OK. You can use debugger only with driver code.

Comment: So i just need to create a file called "spark-defaults.conf" under my $SPARK_HOME/conf/ directory and add spark.jars.packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka_2.10:1.6.0 to the file?

Comment: That's correct. I've linked some explanation about the reason for debugging limitations.

Comment: Thanks a lot, zero323. Great help on this.