# How to debug the function passed to mapPartitions

Tags: apache-spark, mapreduce, pyspark, partitioning

How can I deal with the problem that I can't debug my code with print statements inside the function which I pass to mapPartitions() in pyspark?

Consider the example:

```
def func(kv_iterator):
    for key, value in iterator:
        #do fancy stuff
        print('This print statement does not reach the driver program')
    return [result]

result = someRdd.mapPartitions(func)
```

Inside func i'd like to do lots of work with iterables and indexing, but i can test my code without having excess to variables inside func.

Is it possible to somehow redirect the print statement from let's say one partition to my driver program / output channel?

Answer (score 5):

You can use one of the following:

- use `local` mode. All output should be visible in the console. If it is not, your code is probably never executed - try `result.count()`, `result.foreach(lambda _: None)`, or other action - this is probably the problem here.
- Redirect stdout (and stderr if you want) to file. For basic [`prints`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) use `file` argument:

  ```
  print(*objects, sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)
  ```
- Use remote debugger - [How can pyspark be called in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31245083)

But what is most important - test function outside Spark. Function used with `mapPartitions` should accept `Iterable` (concrete implementation is usually `itertools.chain`) and return `Iterable`.

Comment: Just some minor thing, since it does not make your answer invalid: The return type of a mapped function does not need to be an iterable; this is _not_ mandatory. E.g., you could process a numpy-array in your function and return the whole thing, it does not even have to have rows. The only thing to be aware of is how to treat the returned values after the mapping :)