# Debug pyspark debug map function in pycharm

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, pycharm

How to debug pyspark map function in pycharm editor.
I have selected python `env` varables:

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can pyspark be called in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245083/how-can-pyspark-be-called-in-debug-mode)

Comment: i have followed same question and ans but no luck