# Debugging a Livy job

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, livy

I have a PySpark job that I submit to Livy by using the [Python client](https://github.com/cloudera/livy/blob/master/python-api/src/main/python/livy/client.py).

I would like to debug it, and I've come across [this article](http://ul.io/nb/2018/01/11/remote-debugging-spark-jobs-with-livy/), but it's about Java and uses the configuration value of `spark.driver.extraJavaOptions`, while I need it to be in Python.

So is there a way to debug it as it gets executed (via pdb or any other method)?

Comment: Take a look at [How can PySpark be called in debug mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31245083)

Comment: @user10938362 are you sure that that thread applies to Livy, too?

Comment: Let's say I don't see any reason why it wouldn't.