# How to debug PySpark in local mode from test class

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm writing an aggregation in pysaprk
To this project, I'm also adding test, where I create a session, put some data, and then run my aggregation, and check the results

The code looks like as following:

```
def mapper_convert_row(row):
    #... specific of business logic code, eventually return one string value
    return my_str

def run_spark_query(spark: SparkSession, from_dt, to_dt):
    query = get_hive_query_str(from_dt, to_dt)
    df = spark.sql(query).rdd.map(lambda row: Row(mapper_convert_row(row)))

    out_schema = StructType([StructField("data", StringType())])
    df_conv = spark.createDataFrame(df, out_schema)
    df_conv.write.mode('overwrite').format("csv").save(folder)
```

And here is my test class

```
class SparkFetchTest(unittest.TestCase):

    @staticmethod
    def getOrCreateSC():
        conf = SparkConf()
        conf.setMaster("local")
        spark = (SparkSession.builder.config(conf=conf).appName("MyPySparkApp")
                 .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate())
        return spark

    def test_fetch(self):
        dt_from = datetime.strptime("2019-01-01-10-00", '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
        dt_to = datetime.strptime("2019-01-01-10-05", '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')
        spark = self.getOrCreateSC()
        self.init_and_populate_table_with_test_data(spark, input_tbl, dt_from, dt_to)

        run_spark_query(spark, dt_from, dt_to)
        # assert on results
```

I've added PySpark dependencies via the Conda environment
and running this code via PyCharm. Just to make it clear - there is no spark installation on my local machine except PySpark Conda package

When I set the breakpoint inside the code, it works for me in the driver code, but it does not stop inside **mapper_convert_row** function.

How can I debug this business logic function in a local test environment?
The same approach in scala works perfectly, but this code should be in python.

Comment: I believe reason is: spark is written in scala and hence offer native support Vs for pyspark, python it is mostly interacting with JVM objects using py4j but not natively.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31245083/how-can-pyspark-be-called-in-debug-mode

Comment: Thanks, So the only way is to install spark packages, and then run remote debug? I'm looking for how to do that simpler, without any installation, like scala

Comment: Looked inside references answer, but it is different. I want to debug without any installation, just from code itself. From test function. And I do that, except the debugging inside the map function. In scala it works, but in python no

Answer (score 0):

`pyspark` is a conduit to the `spark` runtime that runs on the `jvm` / is written in `scala`. The connection is through `py4j` that provides a tcp-based socket from the python executable to the jvm. Unfortunately that means

> No local debugging

I'm no more happy about it than you.  I might just write/maintain a parallel code branch in scala to figure some things out that are tiring to do without the debugger.

***Update***  *Pycharm* is able to debug spark programs.  I have been using it nearly daily [Pycharm Debugging of Pyspark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/development/debugging.html)